# Android cast view to its real class

Tags: java, android

I have a `date-dialog-picker` that will be called from different views, where the view may be a `Button`, `TextView`, or any sub class of View.
How I can know who is the caller of the picker at run-time.

and how I can get the real object type out from View, (View is super class of all other widgets, so how can I know if a given widget is a `TextView`, or `Button`, etc...
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `instanceof` to get the class of the caller:

```
if (view instanceof TextView) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instanceof. For example:

```
if (view instanceof TextView) {
     TextView textView = (TextView)view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass arguments to your DialogFragment like this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(AlertDialog.ARGUMENT_VALUE, selfDestructValue.ordinal());
YourAlertDialog dialog = new YourAlertDialog();
dialog.setArguments(args);
dialog.show();
```

and then You can process these arguments via `getArguments` inside your dialog class

Or you can `getContext()` and check type with `instanseof`